# How to find a synonyms in a list of strings using NLTK synsets?

Tags: string, list, nltk, wordnet, synonym

I have a list of strings :

```
words1 =  ['feds', 'move', 'to', 'require', 'cartocar', 'safety', 'communication']
```

I want to find a synsets for each of that words using NLTK wordnet synsets. Firstly, I use one string in my list.
Here's my codes :

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

word = ['feds']

data1 = ' '.join(word)

def getSynonyms(data1):
    synonymList1 = []
    wordnetSynset1 = wn.synsets(data1)

    for synset1 in wordnetSynset1:
        for synWords1 in synset1.lemma_names():
            synonymList1.append(synWords1)
    print synonymList1

print "list of synonyms : ", getSynonyms(data1)
```

and it works. Here's the result :

```
list of synonyms :  [u'Federal', u'Fed', u'federal_official', u'Federal_Reserve_System', u'Federal_Reserve', u'Fed', u'FRS']
```

but when I use a list of strings "words1", it doesn't works and the output is none like this >> [].

anyone can help? thanks

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/alvations/a4a6e0cc24d2fd9aff86

Comment: @alvas wow that's great but I have to use nltk package for this synsets

Comment: Get the synset lemma names out using NLTK Wordnet interface, use the ADM algo to compute the string matching. BTW, there are many other string matching algorithms too. ADM is just one of them.

Comment: @alvas I'm sorry but may I have the example from you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the words individually and not after joining them.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn


def getSynonyms(word1):
        synonymList1 = []
        for data1 in word1:
              wordnetSynset1 = wn.synsets(data1)
              tempList1=[]
              for synset1 in wordnetSynset1:
                 for synWords1 in synset1.lemma_names():
                     tempList1.append(synWords1)
              synonymList1.append(tempList1)
        return synonymList1


word1 =  ['feds', 'move', 'to', 'require', 'cartocar', 'safety', 'communication']
print getSynonyms(word1)
```

Comment: wow thank you very much sir. I thought synset couldn't read a list because I learn many examples that an input always a strings so I change it into strings